# Best method of reducing transient current spikes in LDO

Tags: noise, ldo, proximity-sensor

I'm using a sensor (U3) that essentially switches an LED on and off using (Q3). The led is fed 5V through an LDO (U4) that steps 12V -> 5V. My current issue is that the switching is causing the voltage to be non uniform and my capacitors C4, and C5 are ringing. The 12V line  is coming from another device entirely. I need a solution that will prevent the noise generated by this device to feedback into the device that's powering it. I've tried putting various sized inductors between the 12V source to no avail.

[image: schematic]
[image: waveform]

Comment: Links to data sheets please. A link to the external 12 volt supply and an estimation of its output impedance. Something that describes how the 12 volts connects to this circuit (wire lengths etc.). An explanation of what the oscilloscope trace is. A definition of what "best" means to you and finally a definition of what an acceptable level of ripple voltage is on the 12 volt rail. Have you tried a significant increase in the values of C4 and C5?

Comment: I don't see ringing, that's just output impedance from a load, with a bit of overshoot. Can you show the ringing (on 12V maybe I guess)?

Comment: I would try to increase the capacitors C4/C5 or add some additional ones. Is your LDO rated for the LED current? It seems that the LDO's feedback loop can't cope with your fast switchings. An inductor on the LDO's 12V input will just make things worse because it effectively limits the current transient and produces higher voltage drops. An inductor in front of the LED would probably help but it limits the switching time. A higher capacitance however, serves as an "energy reservoir" during the transients and will help that your LDO has more time to regulate to a stable output.

Answer (score 1):

As Tim Williams says, there is no ringing but instead you are seeing the effects of the poor load regulation of the LDO.  From the data sheet:

[image]

So your only chance is to slow down the change in current.  You might try adding an RC network in the gate for some negative feedback:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXPWYn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The idea is to have the LED current increase more gradually.  I would play with the R's and C's in a SPICE program first.  You'll have to trade off switching time with the reduction in change of load.